When bluetooth is connected, wireless network is having issues
I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 and I have realized that if i use bluetooth with my airpods, my WIFI connection becomes unstable and sometimes disconnected. What could be the issue???

WiFi / Bluetooth can interfere with each other. Other than keeping the devices apart, you could try changing the WiFi channel and/or frequency settings depending on what settings you have.
